# ClientLogin Shutdown: Does this affect Gdata Library?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, gdata, gdata-api

As mentioned [here](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.in/2015/02/reminder-clientlogin-shutdown-scheduled.html), Google is going to shutdown the ClientLogin on April 20, 2015.

We used [GData python client library](https://github.com/google/gdata-python-client/tree/master/src/gdata) to retrieve user information from Google Apps in one of my application. So I just want to confirm whether the below code using ClientLogin function in background.

```
class GoogleAPI:
    GService = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.GService = gdata.apps.service.AppsService(email=email, domain=domain, password=pword)        

    def retriveUser(self, username):        
        try:
            gdata.alt.appengine.run_on_appengine(self.GService, store_tokens=False, single_user_mode=True)
            self.GService.ProgrammaticLogin()               
        except gdata.service.BadAuthentication, e:
            logging.error("AuthError")      

        try:
            user = self.GService.RetrieveUser(username)
            return user
        except:
            logging.error("Error")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to be a bearer of bad news, but your worries are unfortunately well-founded (and I apologize if we didn't clearly communicate and document all the APIs due to be terminated this late April).

`gdata.apps.service.AppsService` is a "Client for the Google Apps Provisioning service" -- and, per https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/, "The deprecation period for the Google Apps Provisioning API is nearly at an end. **On April 20, 2015, we will discontinue service for this API**. This means that service calls to the API are no longer supported, and features implemented using this API will not function after April 20, 2015. You must migrate to the [Admin SDK Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/migrate) as soon as possible to avoid disruptions to your application."

In particular, per the latter URL, "All authorized requests must now use the OAuth 2.0 protocol".  The core motivation for deprecating, and soon shutting down, all the old APIs, was indeed to "eliminate password-only authentication", as http://googledevelopers.blogspot.in/2015/02/reminder-clientlogin-shutdown-scheduled.html puts it...!-(

I would recommend you get going ASAP in migrating to OAuth2 and the new APIs -- I'll be keeping my fingers crossed that the migration is painless and error-free for you, but, if not, do of course post to StackOverflow any problem and SO-appropriate technical question you might encounter (if whatever problem/question you may encounter is specific to the Google Cloud Platform I'll be among those striving to help you -- although this community is so great somebody may easily beat me to the punch!-).